# Using Json And Gson In java web Applications

Tags: java, json, jsp, gson

Hi could anyone please explain me,When we need to use JSon or Gson. What would be the scenario?Could it possible to use Gson or Json in request scope attribute or only during ajax response in the application.

Comment: I thought gson was a library and json a format

Answer (score 0):

Along with ajax **json** can be used as a request.setAttribute and also you can retrieve the json between servlet and JSP.
Check this link out for your understanding..

http://spritiuallyjava.blogspot.in/2012/07/json-with-jsp-and-servlets.html

Comment: I don't want use with any scriptlet.Could it possible?

Comment: what do  u mean by `I don't want use with any scriptlet.`

Comment: I read that document In the jsp to iteratort the request scope.Their the scriplet is used.

Comment: so with what do u want to use?EL?

Comment: Yes would it possible to EL

Comment: How would it possible to populate combo during edit page using json.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson (library) to generate a JSON (format) object that you can use with anything that needs a JSON representation of an object.  In Java web applications, this is often for AJAX responses.

Comment: only during ajax responses? for example to populate combo during the edit page.

Comment: There are other scenarios where you may want to use a JSON object in a response.  AJAX responses happen to be a very common scenario. Populating a combo during page edit would be a very valid example.

Comment: How to populate the combo during page edit using json please expline me.